# Ionic build stuck after ionic build --prod in huge project

Tags: angular, build, ionic3, production, progressive-web-apps

I developing a PWA with a great amount of pages and components.

When I do `ionic build --prod`, ionic starts to build put it get stuck after show `copy finished`.

How could I build my PWA for production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing package.json with

```
  "config": {
    "ionic_source_map": "source-map",
    "ionic_source_map_type": "cheap-source-map"
  },
```

and

```
 "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "node --max-old-space-size=4096 ./node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/bin/ionic-app-scripts.js build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
```

Obs.: In configs, what really matters is "ionic:build"